# Failed to import Module in Py-Script

Tags: python, html, pyscript

i tried using python to connect to a maraidb sql server, while testing the pure python code everything worked perfectly. But the moment i copied the python code in PyScript in my HTML document it stopped working. The issue is py-env does not import mariadb or it imports mariadb but it cant be found. Upon running / opening the HTML-document it fails with following Errorcode in the dev-tools console: 
ValueError: Couldn't find a pure Python 3 wheel for 'mariadb'. You can use 'micropip.install(..,keep_going=True)' to get a list with missing wheels.

I am using following Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"> </script>
<py-env>
- mariadb==1.0.11
</py-env>
</head>
<body>
<main>
</main>
<py-script>
from js import console
import mariadb
console.log("Start")
#print is just for me to see where the Error is caused
print("Hai")
# Connect to MariaDB Platform
try:
  conn = mariadb.connect (
    user= "<username>",
    password="<pw>",
    host="127.0.0.1",
    database="Schuldenliste"

)
except mariadb.Error as e:
    print(f"Error connecting to MariaDB Platform: {e}")

# Get Cursor
sql= "SELECT * FROM Personen"
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(sql)
print(cur.fetchall())
#just to check if it runs trough
print("Hallo Welt")
</py-script>
</body>
</html>
```

The output in my browser is: 
Loading Runtime.... 

Runtime created.... 

Initializing components...

Comment: The error tells you a lot of what you need to know, and so it's not clear what you seek? Pyscript states that it runs, "many popular packages of Python and the scientific stack (such as numpy, pandas, scikit-learn, and more)." That doesn't mean all. Only packages that are pure Python work with pyscript and pyodide or packages that have special versions  that have been made to work with web assembly that is underlying pyodide and pyscript. You already stated you know how to make it work at present and so you have a workaround in hand.

Answer (score 0):

Web browser applications cannot use **sockets** to open connections to other services such as a database server. The only network communication allowed is via the **fetch** style of APIs. This is a security restriction for all applications including JavaScript.

There are several issues with the mariadb package:

1. The package implements some of it features in C. This will require modification to support compilation under the emscripten tools.
2. The packages use APIs such as socket() that do not exist in the web browser. There is no easy to implement solutions to solve this problem.

Comment: @Sokrates19 your comment does not make sense in the context of your question. PHP does not run in the browser.